# Error in Geocoding with Google Directions API

Tags: android, google-maps, driving-directions

I'm having trouble with the Google directions API.

Using it in an android app where the origin is in latitude,longitude BUT the destination is a String. The destination is obtained from the Google places autocomplete. I placed it in an aoutocomplete text view. The problem is in some cases that the string is partially parsed and therefore returning inconsistent results.

For example if the destination is: Karen Shopping Center, Nairobi, Kenya only Nairobi,Kenya will be geocoded. BUT a different location such as Sadili oval, Nairobi, Kenya will work just fine

Please note, that it works at times, I can draw the route between 2 locations